# photogrammetry solutions for raspberry pi 4

Tags: python, pi-4, camera

**Question:**
What open source and automatable software solutions for photogrammetry with Raspberry Pi 4 are available? What are their features, strengths, and weaknesses?

I am not averse to using libraries (Python or Julia) to roll my own solution. Ideally, any solution would be able to handle focus stacking and photogrammetry where the object rotates, the camera rotates, or the lighting conditions change while both the object and camera are stationary (rotating light with camera normal surface of object, like looking down on the earth and backing out the topo surface)

**Setup:**
Raspberry Pi 4 using Arducam 64 megapixel w/autofocus. RGB addressable ring LEDs controllable from the Pi. Also a rotating table but would prefer not to have to use it if at all possible.

**Background:**
I am working on a project using what I think might be termed 2d photogrammetry where I am measuring diameter of a through hole using pictures.

On the side of the hole away from the camera a diffuse colored light is used to provide a mask/contrast then the region viewed through the hole is detected by this color and using known distance to the camera then size of the hole feature is determined. The camera is maintained in a position centered on the hole and perpendicular to its axis.

Since I already have the setup to do the above I thought it might be neat to stretch and try to achieve 3d output as a depth map of the hole. Each hole has a tapered entrance and is non-uniform etc. (the result of a projectile passing through the material)

However, I would prefer not to have to rotate the part or move the camera and I was wondering if I can cheat and use a ring LED array to change the source of the light. I understand this is not the same as moving the viewpoint but it should shadow/light different areas of the hole quite well and I would think work similarly but have to admit I know very little about photogrammetry.

I have a large 100+ array of ring LED's and thought it would be easier than moving the camera or part; particularly given the relatively simple geometry being observed. I am also interested in focus stacking by manually controlling the focal point and understand that can be used to improve photogrammetry.